# Bilinear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}\times E\to F$ have the form $T(\alpha, x)=T(\alpha x)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $E$ and $F$ two vectores space. Show that all bilinear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}\times E\to F$ have the form $T(\alpha, x)=T'(\alpha x)$ with $T'\in\mathcal{L}(E,F)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a bilinear map then $T(\alpha, x) = T(\alpha \times 1, x) = \alpha T(1,x)$. But $T(1,x)=f(x)$ where $f\in \mathcal{L}(E,F)$. Also $T(\alpha, x) = T(1, \alpha x)$.

Comment: why $T(1,x)=f(x)$?

Comment: If $f\in \mathcal{L}(E, F)$ then $f:E\to F$ but also can be writen $f:\mathbb{R}\times E\to F$ and then the property of linear transformation  $f(\lambda v)=\lambda f(v)$ can be writen $f(\lambda\times v)=\lambda f(v)$?

Comment: In general if $B:V×W\to U $ is a bilinear map and $v\in V $ is fixed then by bilinearlity $B (v,\bullet):W\to U $ is a linear map from $W $ to $U $. I dont quite understand what the question is in the second comment.

Comment: Thanks @hamedp, I did not write the statement of the exercise correctly, I think the way it is written right now is correct. What do you think?

Comment: Oh now your $T'$ is my $f$, which is $T(1,\bullet)$.

Comment: So I thought ... thanks!